# How to add data from JTable to JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I have the following issue: I am getting my data in `JTable` and when I click on **receipt** button, I want to add that table data into a `JTextArea`. I want to generate the receipt.

How can I get all the table data into the text area?

Comment: You can use the `getSelectedRow(...)` method of the table to get the currently selected receipt In the table. Then use the `getValueAt(...)` method to get data from the table and then add the the text to the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ListSelectionListener` to your table and in its `valueChanged` method get selected row index by calling `getFirstIndex` and then get the row data by calling `JTable.getModel().getValueAt` and populate your `JTextField` value.

Comment: No need for a ListSelectionListener. The process is started by clicking on a button, at which time you can get the selected row and process the data for the row.

Comment: Let me explain you I am getting data in jtable from 15 textfields, and I am getting that data into 2d array and display my result in jtext area. but the problem is that when I enter my data in 1 field field it only shows one column. But when I enter data in 3 fields it works fine

Comment: DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
 for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
 for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
 for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++){
 jrecieptArea1.append((String) tableData[i][j] );
            jrecieptArea1.append("\t");
}
}
}

Comment: @HamzaAwan, Don't post code in a comment. Update your question so all the relevant information is found in one place.